# Why disappear a cookie of iframe in the http request?

Tags: android, iframe, cookies, android-webview

I write my web page(A page).

The page has a iframe page(B page, not mine) another domain.

When A page load, form.submit() in `document.ready()`.

Form target is iframe and action is B Page, POST method.

B page(in iframe) request to server with cookie and receive responses.

A response(from B) has **P3P** Header.

```
CP='NOI CURa ADMa DEVa TAIa OUR DELa BUS IND PHY ONL UNI COM NAV INT DEM PRE'
```

In this situation:

when I call A page in the PC or mobile browser,

It's ok and confirm a http request with cookie from B.

But I test in the webview of Android app, I can't confirm the cookie.

What is problem? 3rd party cookie issue?

How can I avoid or solve this problm?